# How do you order a list by their distance to a certain number?

Tags: python, list

For example:

Say I had a list

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I want it to order it so that 4 is index 0 and the indexes following are in order of how close they are to 4 (like `[4,3,5,2,6,1,7]`)

How would you do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: First, you need to write the code that tells you how close the number is to 4; then you use that as a `sort` key, as explained in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l.sort(key=lambda i: abs(i-4))
print(l)

>> [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` or `.sort` method with a `key` parameter, to get how close a number is to 4 just subtract by it and get its absolute value:

```py
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: abs(4-x))
[4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0]
```